# Apache server .htaccess query

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

Currently My URL is coming like http://www.example.com/tpjobs/postresume.html

Because I have edited my `.htaccess` file

I want to take off component name from my URL so it will looks like

```
http://www.example.com/postresume.html
```

Is my `.htaccess` file secured?

```
RewriteEngine On        
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

IndexIgnore *
Options +FollowSymLinks All -Indexes

FileETag MTime Size
ExpiresActive On

# Default expiration: 1 hour after request
ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 hour"

# CSS and JS expiration: 1 week after request
ExpiresByType text/css "now plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "now plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "now plus 1 week"

# Image files expiration: 1 year after request
ExpiresByType image/bmp "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jp2 "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/pipeg "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/tiff "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/ico "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/icon "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/ico "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/ico "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.wap.wbmp "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.wap.wbxml "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/smil "now plus 1 year"

# Audio files expiration: 1 year after request
ExpiresByType audio/basic "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType audio/mid "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType audio/midi "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType audio/mpeg "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType audio/x-aiff "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType audio/x-mpegurl "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType audio/x-pn-realaudio "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType audio/x-wav "now plus 1 year"

# Movie files expiration: 1 year after request
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType x-world/x-vrml "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/x-msvideo "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/mpeg "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/mp4 "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/quicktime "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/x-la-asf "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/x-ms-asf "now plus 1 year"

########## End - Optimal expiration time

########## Begin - block bandwidth hoggers 

SetEnvIf user-agent "Indy Library" stayout=1
SetEnvIf user-agent "libwww-perl" stayout=1
SetEnvIf user-agent "Wget" stayout=1

# The following rules are for bandwidth-hogging download tools
SetEnvIf user-agent "Download Demon" stayout=1
SetEnvIf user-agent "GetRight" stayout=1
SetEnvIf user-agent "GetWeb!" stayout=1
SetEnvIf user-agent "Go!Zilla" stayout=1
SetEnvIf user-agent "Go-Ahead-Got-It" stayout=1
SetEnvIf user-agent "GrabNet" stayout=1
SetEnvIf user-agent "TurnitinBot" stayout=1

# This line denies access to all of the above tools
deny from env=stayout
########## End - block bandwidth hoggers 


# Compress text, html, javascript, css, xml, kudos to Komra.de
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain text/html text/xml text/css application/xml application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/javascript application/x-javascript
########## End - Automatic compression of resources

########## Begin - Google Apps redirection, by Sashi
Redirect 301 /mail http://mail.google.com/a/
########## End - Google Apps redirection

########## Begin - Redirect index.php to /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.example.com/ [R,L]
########## End - Redirect index.php to /

########## Begin - Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
########## End - Redirect non-www to www

########## Begin - Redirect www to non-www
## WARNING: Comment out the non-www to www rule if you choose to use this
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R,L]
########## End - Redirect non-www to www

########## Begin - Redirect example.com to www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R]
########## End - Redirect example.com to www.example.com

########## Begin - Force HTTPS for certain pages

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^foobar\.html$ https://www.example.com/foobar.html [L,R]
# Add mode rules below this line


########## Block bad user agents

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^eCatch [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EirGrabber [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailWolf [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Express\ WebPictures [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EyeNetIE [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetRight [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetWeb! [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go!Zilla [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go-Ahead-Got-It [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GrabNet [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Grafula [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^HMView [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} HTTrack [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Stripper [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Sucker [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Indy\ Library [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InterGET [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Internet\ Ninja [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JetCar [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JOC\ Web\ Spider [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^larbin [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LeechFTP [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mass\ Downloader [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MIDown\ tool [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mister\ PiX [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Navroad [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NearSite [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetAnts [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetSpider [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Net\ Vampire [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetZIP [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Octopus [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Explorer [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Navigator [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PageGrabber [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Papa\ Foto [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pavuk [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pcBrowser [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^RealDownload [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ReGet [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SiteSnagger [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SmartDownload [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperBot [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperHTTP [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Surfbot [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^tAkeOut [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Teleport\ Pro [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^VoidEYE [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Image\ Collector [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Sucker [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebAuto [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebCopier [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebFetch [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebGo\ IS [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebLeacher [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebReaper [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebSauger [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ eXtractor [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ Quester [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebStripper [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebWhacker [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus
 ## Note: The final RewriteCond must NOT use the [OR] flag.

 ## Return 403 Forbidden error.
 RewriteRule .* - [F]

 ServerSignature Off
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(HEAD|TRACE|DELETE|TRACK) [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\\r|\\n|%0A|%0D) [NC,OR]

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (<|>|’|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (<|>|’|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(,|;|:|<|>|”>|”<|/|\\\.\.\\).{0,9999} [NC,OR]

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(java|curl|wget) [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (winhttp|HTTrack|clshttp|archiver|loader|email|harvest|extract|grab|miner) [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (libwww-perl|curl|wget|python|nikto|scan) [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (<|>|’|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC,OR]

 #Block mySQL injects
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (;|<|>|’|”|\)|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*(/\*|union|select|insert|cast|set|declare|drop|update|md5|benchmark) [NC,OR]

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.\./\.\. [OR]

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (localhost|loopback|127\.0\.0\.1) [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.[a-z0-9] [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|>|’|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC]
 # Note: The final RewriteCond must NOT use the [OR] flag.

 # Return 403 Forbidden error.
 RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

########## Begin - File injection protection

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]\=http:\/\/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

########## End


## Allow UddeIM CAPTCHA
RewriteRule ^(components/com_uddeim/captcha15\.php)$ $1 [L]

## Allow Phil Taylor's Turbo Gears
RewriteRule ^(plugins/system/GoogleGears/gears-manifest\.php) $1 [L]

## Allow JoomlaWorks AllVideos
RewriteRule ^(plugins/content/jw_allvideos/includes/jw_allvideos_scripts\.php) $1 [L]

# Add more rules to single PHP files here

## Allow Agora attachments, but not PHP files in that directory!
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(\.php)$
RewriteRule ^(components/com_agora/img/members/.*) $1 [L]

# Add more rules for allowing full access (except PHP files) on more directories here

## Uncomment to allow full access to the cache directory (strongly not recommended!)
#RewriteRule ^(cache/.*)$ $1 [L]

## Uncomment to allow full access to the tmp directory (strongly not recommended!)
#RewriteRule ^(tmp/.*)$ $1 [L]

# Add more full access rules here

########## End - Advanced server protection rules exceptions ####

RewriteRule ^(images/stories/*\.(jpe[g,2]?|jpg|png|gif|bmp|css|js|swf|ico|htm[l]?))$ $1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpe[g,2]?|jpg|png|gif|bmp|css|js|swf|ico|htm[l]?)$ - [F,L]

## Disallow visual fingerprinting of Joomla! sites (module position dump)

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)tmpl=component [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)tp= [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)template= [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)tmpl= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

## Disallow PHP Easter Eggs (can be used in fingerprinting attacks to determine
## your PHP version). See http://www.0php.com/php_easter_egg.php and
## http://osvdb.org/12184 for more information
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =PHP[a-z0-9]{8}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{12} [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

## Back-end protection
## This also blocks fingerprinting attacks browsing for XML and INI files
RewriteRule ^(administrator[/]?)$ administrator/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(administrator/index.htm[l]?)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(administrator/index.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(administrator/index[2,3].php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(administrator/(components|modules|templates|images|plugins)/.*\.(jpe[g,2]?|jpg|png|gif|bmp|css|js|swf|htm[l]?))$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^administrator/(.*)$ - [F,L]

## Explicitly allow access only to XML-RPC's xmlrpc/index.php or plain xmlrpc/ directory
RewriteRule ^(xmlrpc/index\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^xmlrpc/(.*)$ - [F,L]

## Disallow front-end access for certain Joomla! system directories
RewriteRule ^(includes/js/.*)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(cache|includes|language|libraries|logs|tmp)/.*$ - [F,L]

## Allow limited access for certain Joomla! system directories with client-accessible content
RewriteRule ^((components|modules|plugins|templates)/.*\.(jp[g,2,eg]?|png|gif|bmp|css|js|swf|ico|htm[l]?))$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^((components|modules|plugins|templates)/.*index\.php(.*))$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(templates/.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(components|modules|plugins|templates)/.*$ - [F,L]

## Disallow access to htaccess.txt and configuration.php-dist
RewriteRule ^(htaccess\.txt|configuration\.php-dist)$ - [F,L]

## SQLi first line of defense
## May cause problems on legitimate requests

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} concat.*\( [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union.*select.*\( [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union.*all.*select.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

########## End - Advanced server protection

########## Begin - Basic antispam Filter
## I removed some common words, tweak to your liking

RewriteCond %{query_string} \bviagra\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bambien\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bblue\spill\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bcialis\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bcocaine\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bejaculation\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \berectile\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \berections\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bhoodia\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bhuronriveracres\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bimpotence\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \blevitra\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \blibido\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \blipitor\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bphentermin\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bprosac\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bsandyauer\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \btramadol\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \btroyhamby\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bultram\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bunicauca\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bvalium\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bviagra\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bvicodin\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bxanax\b [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{query_string} \bypxaieo\b [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

########## End - Basic antispam Filter

########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|\.ini|\.zip|\.json|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a urlpath appear as a direct child page of root "/" create a menu item for it.

menus -> Main Menu -> add menu item